# Having issues returning number of rows along with datetime stamp

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Sample Set

```
ID        TimeStamp       ClientID
1   2013-08-22  08:18:21  XX.XXX.XX.XX
2   2013-08-22  09:18:12  XX.XXX.XX.XX
3   2013-08-22  10:20:12  XX.XXX.XX.XX
```

I need the result to display the number of rows (basically the number of times in use), along with the start and end date/timestamp.  Essentially the first and third row, during the last 24 hours, grouped by end user.
This is what I have so far, but It's not working how I want it to as it's showing each row as normal with a '1' for Times In Use.

```
SELECT     COUNT(*) as 'Times in Use',TimeStamp, ClientID
FROM       tblHistory
WHERE      (TimeStamp > DATEADD(day, - 1, GETDATE()))
GROUP BY   ClientID, TimeStamp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
    ClientID,
    min(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp_start,
    max(TimeStamp) as TimeStamp_end,
    count(*) as cnt
from tblHistory
where
   TimeStamp >= dateadd(hh, -24, getdate())
group by ClientID
```